# Incorrect use of Javascript Variable Hoisting?

Tags: javascript, variables, canvas, hoisting

## The Problem

So, I've tried to use a variable in Javascript before it has been defined. I figured this would be okay due to Javascript Hoisting (http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp). However, I'm getting an undefined error for 'engine.level.tileSize' when trying to employ this technique. I wonder if it's due to it being part of an object... or is it because it is not explicitly part of a function?

## The Code

(Shortened for berevity, here's a codepen with the full working code - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QjKaVG - note: while the code is fully working locally, it won't work on codepen due to missing image assets.)

The code above is my working version. However, when I try to change a couple of lines to the below, the problem becomes evident;

```
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// VIEWPORT CLASS
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
engine.viewport        = {};
engine.viewport.width  = 15 * engine.level.tileSize;
engine.viewport.height = 8 * engine.level.tileSize;

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// LEVEL CLASS
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
engine.level = {};
engine.level.tileSize = 32;
```

Could anyone shed some light on what is going on here and how I could get around this problem?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hoisting only declares variables and functions.

You can't reference an object (and access the value of its properties) before that object exists.

Comment: Thank you, I thought it might be something to do with that. Do you know of a technique in which I'd be able to achieve something like this, or do I just need to define it before I need it?

Comment: @Lewis: put the lower code in a function that you call from above.

Comment: @Lewis — https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll accept this answer when the timer allows.